# Array Implementation In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, comparative-review

### Review

I have written my own implementation of Array in JavaScript with the basic functionalities. Can anyone please review this code and point out the mistakes/how to make the implementation better?

### Optimisation

The `insert(item, index)` function will insert an `item` in the array at the index `index` and shift every element from that index to one position on the right. The current implementation works in O(n) time but also uses O(n) extra space and I was wondering if it is possible to solve this problem without using any extra space?

If you look at the implementation of `remove(index)` function, I am simply shifting every element to the left by one position using the logic `a[i] = a[i+1]` and this works because we do not have to worry about overwriting the data.

However a similar logic will not work for `insert(item, index)` because the moment we shift to the right we are overwriting that value so we need to keep a track of the value being overwritten for every iteration. So far, I have been unable to come up with a logic for the same.

#### My Logic For insert() function

- For the given index **k** copy every item from original array `A` to new array `temp` till index **k** (so **A = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]** with **k = 2** means new array **temp = [10, 20, 30]**)
- Replace the value at index **k** with the value to be inserted (from the above example if we have to insert 99 at index 2 then **temp = [10, 20, 99]**
- Iterate a new loop from index **k** to the end of the original array **A** and copy every element at index **i** of **A** to index **i+1** of **temp** (so **temp = [10, 20, 99, 30, 40, 50]**)

While this works without any issue I feel this logic is not the best and there is a solution possible without copying over to a temporary array. Would appreciate all review and suggestions!

```js
// Array implementation
class ArrayImplementation {
  // When array is created initialize with two properties (length and buffer)
  constructor() {
    this.length = 0; // keep a track of the length of the array
    this.buffer = []; // hold the data
  }

  #validateArray() {
    if (this.length === 0) throw Error("cannot delete from empty array");
  }

  #validateIndex(i) {
    if (i >= this.length) throw Error("array index out of bounds");
    if (i < 0) throw Error("negative index not allowed");
  }

  #copyArray(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      this.buffer[i] = array[i];
    }
    return this.buffer;
  }

  #copyArrayFromIndex(item, index) {
    const temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
      temp[i] = this.buffer[i];
      if (i === index) temp[index] = item;
    }
    for (let i = index; i < this.length; i++) {
      temp[i + 1] = this.buffer[i];
    }
    return temp;
  }

  #shiftLeft(index) {
    for (let i = index; i < this.length - 1; i++) this.buffer[i] = this.buffer[i + 1];
  }

  #prepareData() {
    const t = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) t[i] = this.buffer[i];
    return t;
  }

  // Method to return the data at index i
  at(index) {
    try {
      this.#validateIndex(index);
      return this.buffer[index];
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  // Method to insert item into the array
  push(item) {
    this.buffer[this.length] = item; // insert item at current empty index
    this.length += 1; // increment length
    return this.buffer;
  }

  // Method to remove item from the array
  pop() {
    try {
      this.#validateArray();
      const item = this.buffer[this.length - 1]; // save the last item
      delete this.buffer[this.length - 1]; // remove the last item
      this.length -= 1; // decrement the current length
      return item;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  // Method to insert item at index i in the array
  insert(item, index) {
    try {
      // Insert into the array if array empty or after last index
      if (index === this.length || (index == 0 && this.length === 0)) {
        this.buffer[index] = item;
        this.length += 1;
        return this.buffer;
      }
      // Validate the index
      this.#validateIndex(index);

      // Copy to temporary storage
      const temp = this.#copyArrayFromIndex(item, index);
      console.log(temp);

      // Copy the items of temporary storage into buffer
      // Update the length of the array
      this.#copyArray(temp);
      this.length += 1;

      return this.buffer;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  // Method to delete item at index i in the array
  remove(index) {
    try {
      // Validate the index
      this.#validateIndex(index);
      this.#validateArray();

      // Update the array and index
      this.#shiftLeft(index);
      delete this.buffer[this.length - 1];
      this.length -= 1;

      return this.#prepareData();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  // Method to return the array
  get() {
    return this.#prepareData();
  }
}

const myArray = new ArrayImplementation();
```

Comment: For both insert and remove try Array.splice(). Catching and muting those exceptions is a mistake. Let consumer decide what to do when exception is thrown. All in all I don't see the point in this class...

Comment: There is not much point to the class to be honest, was just learning data structures and algorithms and the instructor was showing Java implementation of the in built array. I know JavaScript so was trying out the same just wanted my code reviewed. Also I did not get the point about catching and mutating the exceptions (not strong in JavaScript!). Would you give some more info?

Comment: There are times when adding functions to `Array.prototype` comes in very handy for a project. And knowing how to not break existing functions is essential here.

Answer (score 1):

In order to insert or remove an item at a given index, you don't need to copy the data back and forth. A simple shift can do instead, like this:

```
insert(index, item) {
    #validateIndex(index);
    const save_index = index;

    while (index < this.length) {
        this.buffer[index + 1] = this.buffer[index];
        index++;
    }

    this.length++;
    this.buffer[save_index] = item;
}

remove(index) {
    #validateArray();
    #validateIndex(index);

    while (index < this.length) {
        this.buffer[index] = this.buffer[index + 1];
        index++;
    }

    this.buffer[--this.length] = null;
    delete this.buffer[this.length];
}
```

Comment: The problem with your insert approach is that whatever element we insert at the position **i** then the element in the array at index **i+1** will get copied to every other index in the array. For example if we have `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]` and insert 99 at index 2 then the output will be `[10, 20, 99, 30, 30, 30, 30]`  because we are not saving the value at index **i+1** before writing it over with the value at index **i**